# R script for getting size of sub directories (i.e., folders) in a directory?

Tags: r, directory

Is there an r function (or script) that can be used to get the size of several folders (sub directories) within a directory? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
sum(file.info(list.files(".", all.files = TRUE, recursive = TRUE))$size)
```

Alternatively, if you'd like to step through the code:

```
#get working directory
getwd()

#list all files in the directory
list.files(".", all.files = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)

#list the size of all individual files
file.info(list.files(".", all.files = TRUE, recursive = TRUE))$size

#sum all file sizes
sum(file.info(list.files(".", all.files = TRUE, recursive = TRUE))$size)
```

Comment: I received the following error when I executed the script: `sum(file.info(list.files(".", all.files = TRUE, recursive = TRUE))$size)` : Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  INTEGER() can only be applied to a 'integer', not a 'double'

Comment: I'm not sure why you would have received that error. I would suggest you step through the code (see amended answer above) to determine where it goes wrong.

Comment: Your solution's explanation is helpful. I was able to execute the code that you posted and acquire the size of an individual folder. Recently, I asked a similar question on stack overflow (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61311014/use-a-pathname-from-a-row-in-a-dataframe-in-a-for-loop/61311108?noredirect=1#comment108463997_61311108) and @LenGreski responded with a solution that was helpful for getting multiple directory sizes using lapply of the base R package.

Answer (score 0):

Using Tim's answer I created a simple function to calculate the size of multiple directories. `NA` values are returned for files.

```
dir_size <- function(x){
  is_dir <- dir.exists(x)
  folder_size <- rep_len(NA_real_, length(x))
  folder_size[is_dir] <- vapply(x[is_dir],
                                function(x) sum(
                                  unname(
                                    file.size(
                                      list.files(
                                        x, full.names = TRUE,
                                        recursive = TRUE, all.files = TRUE
                                      )
                                    )
                                  )
                                ),
                                FUN.VALUE = numeric(1))
  folder_size
}
my_files <- list.files() # Files in working directory
dir_sizes <- dir_size(my_files) # Directory sizes
data.frame(my_files, dir_sizes) # Add to data frame
```