# use a pathname from a row in a dataframe in a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

In an R script, I'd like to use use a pathname from a row in a dataframe in a for loop. For example, I'd like to get the directory size for each of the paths in column one in the following dataframe, by substituting `"."` in the code: 
`sum(file.info(list.files(".", all.files = TRUE, recursive = TRUE))$size)` with a value from the 'pathname' column.

```
                         pathname size
1     F:/Asus/C_drive/WEPP/bitmap    0
2       F:/Asus/C_drive/WEPP/Data    0
3       F:/Asus/C_drive/WEPP/misc    0
4     F:/Asus/C_drive/WEPP/output    0
5       F:/Asus/C_drive/WEPP/runs    0
6      F:/Asus/C_drive/WEPP/tools    0
7 F:/Asus/C_drive/WEPP/watersheds    0
8       F:/Asus/C_drive/WEPP/wepp    0
9    F:/Asus/C_drive/WEPP/weppwin    0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using Base R, using the directory structure from my R Working directory. We'll build a data frame with directory, file name and file size, then aggregate to the directory level.

```
theDirectories <- list.dirs(getwd()) # start with current wd
# for example answer, only use first 2 directories in vector
fileList <- lapply(theDirectories[1:2],function(x){
     files <- list.files(path=x,full.names = TRUE)
     fileName <- list.files(path=x,full.names = FALSE)
     size <- unlist(lapply(files,file.size))
     pathName <- rep(x,length(size))
     data.frame(pathName,fileName,size,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
})
fileSizes <- do.call(rbind,fileList)
aggregate(size ~ pathName,data = fileSizes,sum)
```

...and the output:

```
> aggregate(sizes ~ pathName,data = fileSizes,sum)
                                  pathName    size
1      /Users/lgreski/gitrepos/datascience 3461684
2 /Users/lgreski/gitrepos/datascience/.git  137811
>
```

Comment: That's helpful - thank you! I did find a slight edit in your code that needed to be made. In the `data.frame()` function, the word size was written with two 'e's. Once the second 'e' was deleted, yorr code worked beautifully. I modified it slightly to meet my needs and added a `recursive = FALSE` argument inside the `list.dirs()` function in the first line, as well as a `recursive = TRUE` inside both `list.files()` statements, because I am only interested in folder sizes for the first child directory under the working directory.

Comment: @user3467260 - yes, that was a hand edit after I posted the code, changed the word sizes to size, mistyped one. If you found the answer helpful, please accept and upvote it.

Comment: because I am a new user and have less than 15 reputation, although I upvoted your solution it isn't recorded to the public - sorry. However, I did accept your answer by clicking the check mark. Thanks again.

Comment: @user3467260 - no problem, and welcome to Stackoverflow. As you study R, you'll learn that it is a very useful language.